# Filter Array By Unique Value In Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this 2 dimensional array

```html
let values = [
  [ 6285646346643, 'TCN0018', 200, 2000, 5000, 4000 ],
  [ 6285646346644, 'TCN0018', 300, 2000, 5000, 3000 ],
  [ 6285646346645, 'TCN0019', 100, 1000, 5000, 4000 ]
];
```

I want to filter it by its second column, 'TCNXXX' and then sum its third column so its result should be as object like this:

```
{ TCN0018: 500, TCN0019: 100 }
```

Here is the code that I already implemented:

```js
let values = [
  [ 6285646346643, 'TCN0018', 200, 2000, 5000, 4000 ],
  [ 6285646346644, 'TCN0018', 300, 2000, 5000, 3000 ],
  [ 6285646346645, 'TCN0019', 100, 1000, 5000, 4000 ]
];

let product_id = [];
let obj_product = {};
let amount = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
    if(product_id.indexOf(values[i][1]) === -1)
    {
        console.log(values[i][2])
        product_id.push(values[i][1]);
        amount = values[i][2];
    }    
    obj_product[values[i][1]] = amount;
}

console.log(obj_product);

//result
//{ TCN0018: 200, TCN0019: 100 }
```

Instead the result is:

```
{ TCN0018: 200, TCN0019: 100 }
```

I want to ask, how to achieve the desired result and what I could improve from my code so far?

Comment: You need an `else { amount += values[i][2]; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a `groupBy` logic, basically. Here's how you can implement it:

```js
const values = [
  [ 6285646346643, 'TCN0018', 200, 2000, 5000, 4000 ],
  [ 6285646346644, 'TCN0018', 300, 2000, 5000, 3000 ],
  [ 6285646346645, 'TCN0019', 100, 1000, 5000, 4000 ]
];

const result = Object.create(null) // empty object, similar to {}

for (const value of values) {
  const id = value[1]; // 'TCNXXXX'
  const column = value[2];

  result[id] ??= 0; // initialise if that's the first encounter
  result[id] += column;
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in one simple [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) operation:

```js
const values = [
  [ 6285646346643, 'TCN0018', 200, 2000, 5000, 4000 ],
  [ 6285646346644, 'TCN0018', 300, 2000, 5000, 3000 ],
  [ 6285646346645, 'TCN0019', 100, 1000, 5000, 4000 ]
];

const result = values.reduce((a, [_, k, v]) => {
  a[k] ??= 0; 
  a[k] += v;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

A couple of things to note:

- `[_, k, v]` is used to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the input array. We're interested in the second element (`k`) which will be used as the key, and the third element (`v`) which will be the value added to calculate the totals.
- `a[k] ??= 0` uses a [nullish coalescing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) to set the value for the given key to zero if no value was previously assigned.

Answer (score 1):

```
const values = [
  [ 6285646346643, 'TCN0018', 200, 2000, 5000, 4000 ],
  [ 6285646346644, 'TCN0018', 300, 2000, 5000, 3000 ],
  [ 6285646346645, 'TCN0019', 100, 1000, 5000, 4000 ]
];

let result = values.reduce((r, a) => {
  r[a[1]] = r[a[1]] || 0;
  r[a[1]] = r[a[1]]  + a[2];
  return r
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a relatively straight forward group by operation:

```
const obj_products = values.reduce((groups, row) => {
  const key = row[1];
  const value = row[2];

  if (key in groups) {
    groups[key] += value;
  } else {
    groups[key] = value;
  }

  return groups;
}, {});
```

One of the issues with your current solution is that there was no summation anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't need `product_id` and `amount`, code like this works

```js
let values = [
      [ 6285646346643, 'TCN0018', 200, 2000, 5000, 4000 ],
      [ 6285646346644, 'TCN0018', 300, 2000, 5000, 3000 ],
      [ 6285646346645, 'TCN0019', 100, 1000, 5000, 4000 ]
    ];

    let obj_product = {};
    for(let i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        if (!obj_product.hasOwnProperty(values[i][1])) {
          obj_product[values[i][1]] = 0;
        }
        obj_product[values[i][1]] += values[i][2];
    }

    console.log(obj_product);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's have some functional programming here

```js
let groupBy = fn => a => a
    .map(v => [fn(v), v])
    .reduce((m, [k, v]) =>
            m.set(k, [...(m.get(k) || []), v]),
        new Map)

let pick = k => v => v[k]

let map = fn => a => a.map(fn)

let mapValues = fn => m => new Map([...m].map(([k, v]) => [k, fn(v)]))

let sum = a => a.reduce((s, v) => s + v, 0)

let pipe = (...fns) => v => fns.reduce((v, f) => f(v), v)


//

let values = [
    [6285646346643, 'TCN0018', 200, 2000, 5000, 4000],
    [6285646346644, 'TCN0018', 300, 2000, 5000, 3000],
    [6285646346645, 'TCN0019', 100, 1000, 5000, 4000]
];

transform = pipe(
    groupBy(pick(1)),
    mapValues(
        pipe(
            map(pick(2)),
            sum,
        )
    ),
    Object.fromEntries,
)


result = transform(values)

console.log(result)
```